# What events trigger in Safari when a page is entered via the back button?

Tags: events, safari, onload, document-ready

What events trigger in Safari when a page is entered via the back button?  I've had help from others today but I've tried body onload, doucment.ready, pageshow but none of them work.

It's the last thing to sort on this build and I'm desperate to sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

Check the referrer:

http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol4/javascript_no14.htm

But I think you'll need a server-side language more than Javascript; see 
http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/java-script/147413/147413/detecting-that-browser-back-button-was-clicked/